# Marketing Cloud - report with email open rates and from name

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, reporting

Is there a way to build a report showing basic email metrics (email name, subject, open rates, clicks, etc.) along with the From Name used for each email?

Nothing in the reports catalog seems to offer this, nor does Discover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a custom report using Automation Studio and SQL activities. The required data can be gathered from the Marketing Cloud Data views. The most relevant data views for you might be:

- Click
- Bounce
- Open
- Job
- Sent
- Subscribers

Regarding your specific request for the "FromName", this is one of the columns present on the [Data View: Job.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_job.htm&type=0)

In order to have the report as CSV file, you can use the data extension data extract activity in Automation Studio. If this isn't already provisioned, you need to open a support case and ask for it's activation. You can then download the file from the enhanced FTP or use the AMPscript function `AttachFile` in order to send the report via email.

**Further documentation:**

- [Marketing Cloud Data Views](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_views.htm&type=0)
- [SQL Query Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_using_the_query_activity.htm&type=5)
- [Data Extract Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_use_a_data_extract_activity.htm&type=5)
- [AttachFile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/attachfile.htm)

Comment: I had a feeling SQL was the answer. I have to admit to being a SQL novice myself, but do have all the necessary access. I've been dipping a toe in the water some, but I guess it's time to start learning.

Comment: @Jon Once you have done your first couple of selects and joins you will most certainly enjoy the possibilities this gives you within SFMC ;) As a little help: here you can find a very helpful explanation of the different join-types using venn diagrams: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/
If my answer helped you, please consider marking it as the accepted answer by clicking on the checkmark-icon on the left hand side. Thank you very much and welcome to Salesforce StackExchange! :)

Comment: Thank you - that is indeed a nice explanation. Done and done. Thanks for the help.